# Hi I need some help on understanding how the transposed code works

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not very good at coding so any help in understanding this code would be appreciated. I don't understand how the code works. I think I have a general idea of how it works. I think the variable "I" is somehow assigned to each one of the numbers in the matrix and the row is constantly switching between the 3 to create the groups. The thing is I don't think that this is correct because I don't see the variable "I" assigned to any of the matrix columns neither do I see rows being assigned to the 3 rows from the matrix. Any help would be appreciated in understanding this piece of code. In addition, I am a bit dumb so if you could explain in a very simple manner it would be very helpful. Thank you.

```
matrix = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
]

transposed = []
for i in range(4):
    # the following 3 lines implement the nested listcomp
    transposed_row = []
    for row in matrix:
        transposed_row.append(row[i])
    transposed.append(transposed_row)

transposed
[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the transposed result you can see that each row (sub-list) represents one column from the original matrix where a column is defined as elements sharing a common row (sub-list) index:

Value of `transposed` list and assocaited sub-lists:

```
[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]]
```

The first column (index 0) from `matrix` highlighted in red:

[image: Example column from matrix.]

So, the actual code that performs the transposition is essentially going column by column:

```
for i in range(4):
```

And for each column iterating over each row:

```
for row in matrix:
```

And building a new row from each element in the original matrix row at the column ("i-th") position:

```
transposed_row.append(row[i])
```

When the new transposed row is complete (after all original rows have been iterated over) for the current column, the new row is appended to the `transposed` list and the process starts all over again with the next column (next value of `i`):

```
transposed.append(transposed_row)
```